# How to reference html element from included js-file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I created this test case which works as expected:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="site.js"></script>

<script>
function click_me() {
    deActivateButton("Please wait ..", "#btnX");
    activateButton("Click me 2", "#btnX");
}
</script>

<button type="button" id="btnX" onclick="click_me(); return false;">Click me
</button>
```

And then two small functions kept in site.js to deactivate/activate my buttons:

```
function deActivateButton(btnText, id) {
    $(id).text(btnText);
    $(id).prop("disabled", true);
}

function activateButton(btnText, id) {
    $(id).text(btnText);
    $(id).prop("disabled", false);
}
```

This works fine, but fails when I use the code in my application. I'm using web forms with a master page. The master page loads include file:

```
<%Response.WriteFile("Content/Files/master_include_head.html");%>
```

And then in master_include_head.html I include the actual javascript functions like this:

```
<script src="site.js"></script>
```

What can I be doing wrong here? There are no error messages, it just dies. Shouldn't I be able to reference the id of the clicked button with this design, or is the reference to the button lost because of the way I include files? Can it be a cache problem?

Comment: do you include <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> in the other site as well?

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. Probably a script loading issue. Show the rendered page head rather than server-side code. 

On another note, you should probably use event handlers rather than inline onclick, and you can chain your statements in your activate/deactivate functions, like `$(id).text(...).prop(...);`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not just setting and then clearing then immediately clearing the value in your code?

So you are activating then immediately de-activating your button?

Just a little note. Why not use jQuery to attach your click events as follows:

```
$("#btnX").click(function(e) {
     // Do stuff
});
```

Side note. I'm not sure there's any need for the return false; statement in your onclick. Typically this would just contain the function name. return false; can be used in functions to prevent event bubbling, as you've set it I'm not sure it will have any effec

Comment: Val() is for form elements, mostly. Text() and html() do what's required here.